# Responsive HTML not showing on iPhone but showing in Chrome developer tools and Safari Mobile, yes i have viewport

Tags: html, css

really new user, hope I'm posting this right.

I'm trying to get responsive HTML to work on my phone, but I'm running into really strange problems. The responsive html on my page doesn't seem to be working. Even stranger, I copied the page and the issues on that page are different, even though the code should be identical.

I am working on
http://www.nokillshelter.net/final.html

http://www.nokillshelter.net/finalfinal.html

Both should be the same code but both are not picking up the responsive CSS properly. I'd post code, but its very long at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us" class="no-js">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>NoKillShelter Music</title>
<meta name="description"
      content="NoKillShelter Music">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- ================4avicons ================== -->
<!-- Standard -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">
<!-- Retina iPad Touch Icon-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/favicon-retina-ipad.png">
<!-- Retina iPhone Touch Icon-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/favicon-retina-iphone.png">
<!-- Standard iPad Touch Icon-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/favicon-standard-ipad.png">
<!-- Standard iPhone Touch Icon-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="img/favicon-standard-iphone.png">

<!-- ============== Resources style ============== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-multi-scrollnew.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="thelist">
    <h5>NoKillShelter Releases</h5>
    <br><img id="movinglogo" src="/img/LogoNKS-Imma.gif">
    <div id="songs">
        <a id="Longshot" href="https://awal.lnk.to/vmjynlm">
            <span>Longshot</span>
        </a>
        <br><a id="Sweetheart" href="https://awal.lnk.to/NoKillShelter-Sweetheart"><span>Sweetheart</span>
    </a>
        <br><a id="FairyQuing" href="https://awal.ffm.to/mxnkqxq">
        <span>FairyQuing</span>
    </a>
        <br><a id="JustSeeTheCoast" href="https://awal.lnk.to/JustSeetheCoast">
        <span>Just See The Coast</span>
    </a>
        <br><a id="BalancedLove" href="https://awal.lnk.to/BalancedLove">
        <span>Balanced Love</span></a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
      /* Small Devices, Tablets @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 5.5rem;
    }

    #thelist {
        top: 69px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    h5 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }

    #movinglogo {
        max-width: 17%;
        top: 55px;
        left: -5px;
        position: absolute;
    }


    button {
        white-space: nowrap
    }

    .album {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }

    #info .content {
        padding: 0 5%;
    }

    .block-team img.team-member {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .album {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 5.5rem;
    }

    #thelist {
        top: 69px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

       #thelist button {
        whitespace: inherit;
        button-width: 200px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    #movinglogo {
        max-width: 17%;
        top: 55px;
        left: -5px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Comment: I see some erros in the console, fix those first. Some scripts can not be loaded.

Comment: Those were just google scripts for fonts that weren't secure because I was missing an s in https, any idea what might be causing it. I have it showing up on chrome on my phone as it should, but not safari.